# Standardizing regression coefficients changed significance

Tags: r, regression, scale, linear-regression

I originally had this formula:
`lm(PopDif ~ RailDensityDif + Ports + Coast, data = Pop)` and got a coefficient of 1,419,000 for RailDensityDif, -0.1011 for ports, and 3418 for Coast. After scaling the variables: `lm(scale(PopDif) ~ scale(RailDensityDif) + scale(Ports) +  scale(Coast), data = Pop)`, my coefficient for RailDensityDif is 0.02107 and 0.2221 for Coast, so now Coast is more significant than RailDensityDif. I know scaling isn't supposed to change the significance—why did this happen?

Comment: *"so now Coast is more significant than RailDensityDif"* What is this statement based on? All you're reporting are parameter *estimates*; please make your post reproducible by including (1) sample data, and (2) code to reproduce parameter estimates for both models. Perhaps useful in this context (and for future posts) is advice on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also relevant is the following post that explains how p-values characterising the statistical significance of parameters in a linear model can in fact change when standardising (scaling) variables: [Standardized estimates give different p-value with a glmer/lmer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180904/standardized-estimates-give-different-p-value-with-a-glmer-lmer)

Comment: To expand on my comments above please take a look at my post below for a practical example (based on `mtcars`).

Comment: This is too old to migrate, but really belongs on CrossValidated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tldr;** The *p*-values characterising the statistical significance of parameters in a linear model may change following scaling (standardising) variables.

---

As an example, I will work with the `mtcars` dataset, and regress `mpg` on `disp` and `drat`; or in R's `formula` language `mpg ~ disp + drat`.

### 1. Three linear models

We implement three different (OLS) linear models, the difference being different scaling strategies of the variables.

1. To start, we don't do any scaling.

   ```
   m1 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + drat, data = mtcars)
   ```
2. Next, we scale values using `scale` which by default does two things: (1) It centers values at `0` by subtracting the mean, and (2) it scales values to have unit variance by dividing the (centered) values by their standard deviation.

   ```
   m2 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + drat, data = as.data.frame(scale(mtcars)))
   ```

   Note that we can apply `scale` to the `data.frame` directly, which will scale values by column. `scale` returns a `matrix` so we need to transform the resulting object back to a `data.frame`.
3. Finally, we scale values using `scale` without centering, but scaling values to have unit variance

   ```
   m3 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + drat, data = as.data.frame(scale(mtcars, center = F)))
   ```

### 2. Comparison of parameter estimates and statistical significance

Let's inspect the parameter estimates for `m1`

```
summary(m1)$coef
#               Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept) 21.84487993 6.747971087  3.237252 3.016655e-03
#disp        -0.03569388 0.006652672 -5.365345 9.191388e-06
#drat         1.80202739 1.542091386  1.168561 2.520974e-01
```

We get the *t* values from the ratio of the parameter estimates and standard errors; the *p*-values then follow from the area under the curve of the pdf for `df = nrow(mtcars) - 3` (as we have 3 parameters) where `x > |t|` (corresponding to a two-sided *t*-test). So for example, for `disp` we confirm the *t* value

```
summary(m1)$coef["disp", "Estimate"] / summary(m1)$coef["disp", "Std. Error"]
#[1] -5.365345
```

and the *p*-value

```
2 * pt(summary(m1)$coef["disp", "Estimate"] / summary(m1)$coef["disp", "Std. Error"], nrow(mtcars) - 3)
#[1] 9.191388e-06
```

Let's take a look at results from `m2`:

```
summary(m2)$coef
#                 Estimate Std. Error       t value     Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept) -1.306994e-17 0.09479281 -1.378790e-16 1.000000e+00
#disp        -7.340121e-01 0.13680614 -5.365345e+00 9.191388e-06
#drat         1.598663e-01 0.13680614  1.168561e+00 2.520974e-01
```

Notice how the *t* values (i.e. the ratios of the estimates and standard errors) are different compared to those of `m1`, due to the centering and scaling of data to have unit variance.

If however, we don't center values and only scale them to have unit variance

```
summary(m3)$coef
#              Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)  1.0263872 0.31705513  3.237252 3.016655e-03
#disp        -0.4446985 0.08288348 -5.365345 9.191388e-06
#drat         0.3126834 0.26757994  1.168561 2.520974e-01
```

we can see that while estimates and standard errors are **different** compared to (unscaled) results from `m1`, their respective ratios (i.e. the *t* values) are **identical**. So (default) `scale(...)` will change the statistical significance of parameter estimates while `scale(..., center = FALSE)` will not.

It's easy to see *why* dividing values by their standard deviation does not change the ratio of OLS parameter estimates and standard errors when taking a look at the closed form for the OLS parameter estimate and standard error, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Estimation).

Comment: Note that p-value **only changes for the intercept** in this case. Centring will only change p-values for coefficients other than the intercept if model contains interactions.